# I'm working on a mini banking system webapp using flask. how do i make the balance webpage display the available balance in the user database

Tags: python, database, csv, flask

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>dashboard</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/project.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header><h1>Finance</h1><br>
            <div class="slogan">Your secure safe...</div> 
         </header>
         <h2 class="reg">Your Account Balance is #{{balance}}</h2>    
    </body>
</html>
```

#this is the code for the dashboard below, which leads to the balance page. i don't know how to make the balance page display the actual balance that is in the csv of each user
.

```
   @app.route("/dashboard", methods = ["GET","POST"])
    def dashboard():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            
       
        return render_template("dashboard.html")
    
    @app.route("/balance.html", methods = ["GET","POST"])
    def balance():
        if request.method == "POST":
             email = request.form['email']
             group = df.groupby("email")
             if email in df.values:
                ok = group.get_group(email)
                id = ok.iloc[0,7]
                users = pd.read_csv(f"{id}.csv")
        return render_template("balance.html", balance = users.iloc[-1,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your html code to this-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>dashboard</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/project.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header><h1>Finance</h1><br>
            <div class="slogan">Your secure safe...</div> 
         </header>
         <h2 class="reg">Your Account Balance is {{balance}}</h2>  
    </body>
</html>
```